Tool to record process network usage over time
I'd like to have a record of which processes are using the network and when on my Linux server.  Most tools I see (nethogs, iftop, etc.) are designed to only show what's happening right now on the server which isn't too useful to me.  I'd like to get graphs of what happened over the last week, for example, and on a per-process basis too; not just overall network usage.  Is there anything that can do this?
I'd also like this to record processes started via crontab.  So if I have a process being started every 5 minutes, running briefly then stopping, it should record all the data that that process send/received too.  As each invocation would have a different PID I'd probably want to group these processes by commandline instead.

A novel approach might be to simply enable systemd's IP
accounting
throughout the system. See man systemd.resource-control for the
IPAccounting= setting.
The above article explains how you can turn on some basic accounting in a
systemd Unit. For example, we can use systemd-run to create a service and
run a ping command to the internet:
$ sudo systemd-run -p IPAccounting=yes -u mytest -t --wait ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
...
IP traffic received: 84B
IP traffic sent: 84B

You can see 2 extra lines of output giving the total number of bytes sent
and received over the network.
Note, you need to be root to enable IP accounting in this way.
You also get the same information logged in the journal (The date and time
headings have been removed for clarity):
$ journalctl -u mytest -n 3 --no-pager
 Started mytest.service - /usr/sbin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8.
 mytest.service: Deactivated successfully.
 mytest.service: ..., received 84B IP traffic, sent 84B IP traffic.

There is also a more easily parsed output that includes the total packet counts:
$ journalctl -u mytest -n 1 -o verbose | grep IP
    IP_METRIC_INGRESS_BYTES=84
    IP_METRIC_INGRESS_PACKETS=1
    IP_METRIC_EGRESS_BYTES=84
    IP_METRIC_EGRESS_PACKETS=1
    MESSAGE=mytest.service: ... received 84B IP traffic, sent 84B IP traffic.

I'm not going to test this, but in principle you could create a slice with
IP accounting enable, then run all your processes within that slice.
Or dynamically set the flag in the system slice, root slice, user slice or
any existing slice (such as a given user's session slice):
systemctl set-property system.slice IPAccounting=yes

You can enable the setting system-wide
by adding this option to /etc/systemd/system.conf and rebooting:
DefaultIPAccounting=yes

